# Only update changed values for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, insert-update

I have a list of checkboxes that are assigned either a value of 1 or 0 that all get passed in the $_POST variable.

My current sql statement inserts all of them correctly but when I change a value and run the sql statement again, it updates my "updated_at" column for all the items.

Is there a way to only update changed values so it doesn't update the "updated_at" column for every entry? id is my primary key and site_id is unique.

SQL Statement:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO admin_sites2 (site_id,created_at,active)
                VALUES ('$key',now(),'$value')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY
                UPDATE active = $value,
                updated_at = now()
               ";
```

Comment: id must be part of the query. but you don't have it. just a little oversight I assume. fix it and you should be fine.

Comment: @hakre: I'm not sure I understand your comment. It looks as if `site_id` is a unique key on this table; there has to be at least one unique constraint in order to raise the "duplicate key" exception; and we wouldn't want to update the value of that unique key.

Comment: @spencer7593: I assumed that primary key - not a unique key - is required to have `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` working. I might be wrong but I can imagine that is part of the issue and would qualify as a quick fix.

Comment: @hakre: the "duplicate key" exception can be raised for any unique constraint, whether it's a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY. (A table can have multiple unique constraints; whichever key is identified in the "duplicate key" exception, that will be the key value used by the UPDATE action to identify the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you use the special VALUES() function to reference the value that would have been inserted into a column (if the insert had succeeded).

You can use an expression that compares the current value of the column to the newly provided value, and conditionally return either the current value of the column, or a new expression.

For example:

```
            INSERT INTO admin_sites2 (site_id,created_at,active)
            VALUES ('$key',now(),'$value')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE updated_at = IF(active=VALUES(active),updated_at,NOW()),
            active = VALUES(active)
```

The expression **`IF(a,b,c)`** works like this: it evaluates `a` as a boolean; IF `a` is TRUE then return `b` else return `c`.

In the example above, if the current value of the `active` column is the same as the new value being inserted/assigned, the `IF()` expression returns the current value of the `updated_at` column. (That means that the value of the `updated_at` column won't be changed, since it's assigning the value that's already stored.) Otherwise, the value of `NOW()` will be assigned to the `updated_at` column.

I believe it's important to do the check of the current value of the `active` column BEFORE the assignment is made to the `active` column.  (Note that the assignment to `updated_at` appears BEFORE the assignment to `active`.)

This is because of the way MySQL processes values in SQL. MySQL doesn't maintain a consistent snapshot view of the row ('at the start of the statement').  After a new value is assigned to a column, later references to that column will return the newly assigned value rather than the value it was before the statement started making changes to the row.

Comment: is there a trick / alternative when there are 50 non key columns to compare? ie. not just the active column in this example, but say there are 50 columns we need to check for update, before deciding to keep the same updated_at

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure this can be done in a single query why don't you just make multiple queries? Just select the `active` column where `site_id` equals $key. If you there is no result do an insert and set `updated_at`. If there is and the value is different, update both columns. Else do nothing

Comment: There's a couple of reasons not to do that. That approach doubles the number of roundtrips to and from the database, there's more overhead for statement parsing, locking, etc. that may not be a performance concern on a lightly loaded system, but it does impact scalability. This approach also has a chance for a race condition. There's a small window of time between the two statements (the SELECT and the UPDATE) for another session to modify (or delete) the row. Probably not a concern in this specific use case, but is a consideration in the more general case.